# Material ripple effect on table row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'm playing with google material design bootstrap theme by [FezVrasta](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)

Most of components working and looking great, but ripple effect on table row not working properly for me.

Demo: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kasaras/qrj536qd/)

```
table > tr > td {position:absolute;}
```

Absolute position helps but destroys table structure.

Comment: the fiddle link is broken... By the way, *"ripple effect on table row not working properly "* -  does google material specification say table rows should have ripple effect?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add anything other than `<td>` into a `<tr>`.

In other words, You can only have this effect for `<td>`. This is an HTML limitation.

Comment: Yes but tjis not solve the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasaras/qrj536qd/6/)

Comment: You cannot use `position: relative` on table elements, so I think you need to wrap cells within `<div>`s. I'm not sure if this can be done without `<div>s`. http://jsfiddle.net/qrj536qd/8/